# Webpack + Angular2 AOT: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack, angular2-aot

in this set-up, how do you transpile the angular2 library being imported from the generated ngfactory files?

the current app is a combination of the webpack + aot cookbook based on the angular docs

angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html
angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

I have a working POC where you can replicate the issue from this repo:

https://github.com/jetlogs/Angular2-AOT-Localization

after you've done the compilation / bundling, you can open the 2 files:

non-aot.html - this is the non-aot version of the same app, and it loads fine
aot.html - this file fails with:

> ng_module_factory.js?95b1:13 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

**Expected behavior**
the expected behavior is that aot.html and non-aot.html should have the same behavior

**Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions**

clone the repo, then 
run these commands on the working directory:

```
npm install
npm postinstall
npm run build
```

then open aot.html to reproduce the issue

Is there any way on how to fix the import statements from the imported angular2 libraries? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I've tried transpiling the angular2 source files which are in ES2015 by using the babel-loader:

```
{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            include: [
                /node_modules(\\|\/)@angular/
            ],
            exclude: [
                /\.umd\.js$/
            ],
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        },
```

it now compiles without issues with ES6 incompatibilities, however, it now encounters a new error only for `aot.html`:

> core.umd.js?e2a5:3272Uncaught Error: No provider for NgZone!

any reason why transpiled angular2 source codes being referenced by the AOT compiler are cdausing NgZone issues?

I've updated the repo above to reflect my latest changes

**UPDATE2: 10/13/16**

Updated to Angular 2.1
still the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The System.import syntax used in ng_module_factory.js is ES6 style module loading. Webpack 1, which you are probably using, does not support this syntax.

A workaround might be to transpile the Angular ES6 modules to ES5 with require() syntax, but you already tried this without success.

However you might consider switching to Webpack 2, which fully supports ES6 style imports and is very close to its stable release. The compilation worked for me this way without changing anything except for the webpack config which uses a new syntax for some parts.

Comment: was able to resolve this long ago by switching to webpack2.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a wrong import generated by IDE:

`import { Component, Output } from "@angular/core/src/metadata/directives";`

Instead of:

`import { Component, Output } from "@angular/core";`